# Deleting part of string

Tags: asp.net, string, substring

I want to delete the part of string existing after "|". For Example String s = HelloWorld|ABCD i want to delete ABCD.

I want to do it in asp.net. Help Will be much appreciated. 
subString method might be used for this but i dont know how to do it.
Kindly help me out with this.

Comment: `This question does not show any research effort`

Comment: @GibralterTop thanku for the comment, if i have not pasted my effort here so it doesn't mean i haven't done anything. For me posting the question here is the last thing. I am working on a university project and this was the most minor part of it. so stop being judgmental and giving negative points :) 
Thanks

Comment: Then show what you've tried and researched then negative points will be undone.

Comment: sure i will, let me get back to my machine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int pipeIndex = s.IndexOf("|");
s = pipeIndex == - 1 ? s : s.Substring(0, pipeIndex);
```

This is the  most efficient way, maybe you find this more readable:

```
s = s.Split('|')[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will try this and will mark it as answer :)

Comment: @AhsanHasan: i have added another approach